# How can i use "Use [database]" transactions within IF statements in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement

I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
IF(@@SERVERNAME = 'SERVER1')
BEGIN
  USE Appt
END
IF(@@SERVERNAME = 'SERVER2')
BEGIN
  USE ApptDEMO
END
```

At work, our database for production is `"Appt"` but the one for test environment is `"ApptDEMO."`
They're the same thing, but they're just named differently.

It runs fine in the test environment because both `"Appt"` and `"ApptDEMO"` exist there (it just doesnt use `"Appt"`).
But in production, it tells me that "ApptDEMO" doesn't exist.

I want to create a script that I don't need to make x amount of different scripts for different environments.
Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this without doing dynamic SQL due to the way SQL processes USE statements. 

USE statements are also scoped to the batch they are executed in.

When you say "it runs fine in test" - what runs fine in test? The script?

What do your scripts do? Have you considered using other SQL features (maybe SYNONYMS can help you here?). Just trying to work out if there's a better way for you to achieve what you want...

Comment: I agree with @Charleh. This sounds like a prime example of using synonyms. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx

Comment: (I'm new to this site...haha)
Thanks for the speedy answered everyone! I'm going to look into SYNONYMS and see if it helps me out!

Comment: I'm not really understanding how that would help me out. I don't want to hard code anything...I just want it to select the correct database i'm using depending on the Server I'm using. 
I'm probably just not understanding it correctly.

Comment: My script is trying to set a customer up with an account. We have to test it all in the test environment before we can push it production.

When I said it runs fine in the test environment, I mean that since "Appt" and "ApptDEMO" both exist in the test environment, it executes fully.         But in the production environment, only "Appt" exists, so when it gets to the "Use ApptDEMO" line within the IF statement, it errors out.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are putting code to setup multiple databases (which may or may not exist) in the same script file, are you running the same script on both databases? If so, just make one script and change the database context to the one you want to run it on...

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with dynamic SQL):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
IF (@@SERVERNAME = 'SERVER1')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'USE Appt'
END
ELSE IF (@@SERVERNAME = 'SERVER2')
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'USE ApptDEMO'
END

IF (@sql != N'')
BEGIN
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Comment: This only scopes the USE to the batch executed in `sp_executesql`...you'd have to execute more statements in that batch in order to do any work. It's useless unless you put more statements in the `@sql` variable

Comment: @Charleh: I focalize my script on DB choose. In the sql variable, you can put other statements

Answer (score 0):

Database can't be changed dynamically (`USE [DB]`) other then making the query dynamic.

Below code may clarify your understanding.

```
SELECT DB_NAME();
-- Master --Default Database

SELECT @@SERVERNAME
-- SERVER1

DECLARE @USEDB NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
CASE @@SERVERNAME WHEN 'SERVER1' THEN 'USE [Appt];'
                  WHEN 'SERVER2' THEN 'USE [ApptDEMO];'
END -- Same as IF statement

EXEC(@USEDB) -- The database [Appt] will be changed within this batch, not outside.
SELECT DB_NAME();
-- Master --Default Database

DECLARE @MyQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select DB_NAME();'
DECLARE @UseDBWithQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = @USEDB + @MyQuery

EXEC(@UseDBWithQuery)
-- Appt
```